# Merge 2 log files in nodejs

Tags: node.js, angular, multer

I have a file saved in my server, suppose its path is `data/x.log`. I upload a new file to the server:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

import { IResponse } from 'src/app/interfaces/response.interface';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';

const ENDPOINT = environment.apiUrl + '/log';

@Injectable()
export class HttpUploadService {
    constructor(
        private http: HttpClient,
    ) { }

    public uploadLogFile(file: File): Observable<IResponse> {
        const baseUrl: string = ENDPOINT;
        
        const postData = new FormData();
        postData.append('file', file);

        return this.http.post<IResponse>(baseUrl, { postData });
    }

}
```

This is also a log file. My order is to merge these 2 files to the same location `data/x.log` path.
The merge is like append. just add the second file content after the first one.

How can I do it my server code with node.js?

This is my controller for this:

```
const saveLogFile = async (req, res) => {
}
```

In my first approach I tried to do it with `multer` package:

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination(req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, './data');
    },
    filename(req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, `x.log`);
    }
});
```

But as far as I know it will just override the file content with no merge.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't heard of upload libraries supporting append. You'd most likely have to do it manually without using a library that automatically stores files on disk.

You could, for example, use busboy to access the incoming file as a stream and then append it to your desired file. Once you get a hold of the incoming stream, you can append to an existing file with something like:

```
const fs = require("fs");    
const destination = fs.createWriteStream("data/x.log", {
  flags: "a" // "a" for append
});
incomingFile.pipe(destination);
```